# How to change the routing based on url in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 urls /dev and /app. My angular routes is as follows

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'homeTemp',
          controller: 'homeCtrl',
        }).
        when('/home/:pageId', {
          templateUrl: 'homeTemp',
          controller: 'homeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/apps', {
          templateUrl: 'devTemp',
          controller: 'devCtrl',

        }).
         when('/app/:appId', {
          templateUrl: 'devAppTemp',
          controller: 'devCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
```

Now when my url is /dev#/apps it loads the dev controller and when it's /apps#/home it loads the home controller

What change do I need to add in my routes so that when the url is just /dev it loads the dev controller

Currently because of the otherwise it redirects to /dev#/home

Comment: When you'r route is `/dev#/home` by default it will load dev controller. You may split url routes and check whether any controller exists with param passed. And if exists redirect from `dev` controller :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a root level controller that just checks the url and redirects you as needed.

In your $routeProvider add

```
    when('/', {
      controller: 'isDevCtrl',
      template:""
    })
```

Then in isDevCtrl look at the url and redirect accordingly

```
yourApp.controller("isDevCtrl", function($location){

    if($location.path() == '/dev'){
        $location.path("/apps")
    }else{
        $location.path("/home")
    } 

});
```